# Have Process Work for More than One Row in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have some VBA code that updates values of many cells based on the value of a preceding cell. At the moment, I can get it to work for one row of info. However, I'd like for it to work for more than one row. I've been writing and copy+pasting pieces of code, so there's a good chance that it's just a lack of coherence.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rwIndex As Integer
For rwIndex = 4 To 400
If Target.Address = Cells(rwIndex, 3) Then

    If Range(Target.Address).Value = "Intrinsic" Then
        Dim LYVMessage
        LYVMessage = "Enter Last Year's Value"
        Cells(rwIndex, 5).Value = InputBox(LYVMessage)
    Else
        Cells(rwIndex, 5).Value = "NA"
        Cells(rwIndex, 6).Value = "NA"
        Cells(rwIndex, 9).Value = "NA"
        Cells(rwIndex, 10).Value = "NA"
        Cells(rwIndex, 11).Value = "NA"
        Cells(rwIndex, 12).Value = "NA"
        Cells(rwIndex, 7).Value = "NA"
        Cells(rwIndex, 8).Value = "NA"
        QMessage = "Enter whether Quantity is a Fixed Variable (1) or Random Variable (Logistic or Triangular)"
        Cells(rwIndex, 13).Value = InputBox(QMessage)
        PMessage = "Either Enter a Fixed Value for Price, or Enter Whether it is a Random Variable (Logistic or Triangular)"
        Cells(rwIndex, 14).Value = InputBox(PMessage)
    End If
End If
Next rwIndex
End Sub
```

When I update the target cell, I get an error that says: "Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined."

Can anyone tell me what's going on?

Comment: Where did you put that code? It needs to go on the SHEET and NOT in a module since it's a Change Event

Comment: It's not Cell but Cells with an S. But this code won't do squat either. Do you only want to change the values if you change something in column C and between rows 4 and 400? Is that it?

Comment: It's in the sheet. And yes, I only want values to change if something in column C is changed.

Comment: See my answer with its code. If it can be in all column C, modify the If statement to just be "If c = 3 Then...". If it solved your problem mark it as such please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several problems: it's not "Cell" but "Cells". Also this code needs to be in the code of the worksheet and not in a module.
And it won't do anything as is...

Here is a code that should do what I understood you want to do: change the values if you modify a cell in column "C" that is between rows 4 and 400 included

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' Turn screen updating off
Application.EnableEvents = False  ' Turn the events off to avoid trigerring this macro within this macro when changing cell values

Dim r As Integer, c As Integer
Dim Message As String

' Get the Target cell's row and column (the cell you just modified and that triggered this macro)
r = Target.Row
c = Target.Column

' If the target cell is in column 3 and between rows 4 and 400 included
If c = 3 And (r > 3 And r < 401) Then

    If Target.Value = "Intrinsic" Then

        Message = "Enter Last Year's Value"
        Cells(r, 5).Value = InputBox(Message)

    Else
        Cells(r, 5).Value = "NA"
        Cells(r, 6).Value = "NA"
        Cells(r, 9).Value = "NA"
        Cells(r, 10).Value = "NA"
        Cells(r, 11).Value = "NA"
        Cells(r, 12).Value = "NA"
        Cells(r, 7).Value = "NA"
        Cells(r, 8).Value = "NA"

        Message = "Enter whether Quantity is a Fixed Variable (1) or Random Variable (Logistic or Triangular)"
        Cells(r, 13).Value = InputBox(Message)

        Message = "Either Enter a Fixed Value for Price, or Enter Whether it is a Random Variable (Logistic or Triangular)"
        Cells(r, 14).Value = InputBox(Message)

    End If

End If

' Turn events and screen updating back on
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I changed it to Cells (for each), but now nothing happens at all when I change a cell in column C (no update, no error)

Comment: Just a note that "NA" can be set in those cells in one go: `Union(Cells(r, 5), Cells(r, 6), Cells(r, 9), etc..).Value = "NA"`

Answer (score 0):

In line 4 of your code you are comparing the address of the target cell (String) to the Cell (Range).

Instead of this:

```
If Target.Address = Cells(rwIndex, 3) Then
```

you should try this

```
If Target.Address = Cells(rwIndex, 3).Address Then
```

Hope that works !!!